# поменять http://localhost:3000 при запросе на some.ru

Tags: reactjs

в `.env.developmet` прописал
NODE_ENV=development
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://some.ru

но при запроск

```
axios
                .get('/BaseInfo')
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('response', response.data)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
```

Он все равно подставляет http://localhost:3000
Вопрос, как с http://localhost:3000 проситься на some.ru ???

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо использовать эту переменную окружения. Пример:

```
axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/BaseInfo')
```

Более подробная информация в [документации](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

---

Можно создать инстанс `axios` с необходимым `baseURL`:

```
export const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
})
```

и далее используем

```
instance.get('/BaseInfo')
```

Comment: Да, это прекрасно работает, но я бы хотел по дефолту установить любой домен и не клеить его к запросу.

Comment: Тогда можно создать `instance` `axios` с необходимым `baseURL`:
`export const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
})`

И далее использовать этот инстанс.